# Elegant solution to read application settings by parsing xml file (app.config)

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading the app.config settings by a seperate project using a xml reader. The app.config can not be read by Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting in a different dll. Now I am trying to finde a proper Solution how to read different settings in different formats (StringCollection, String, ...).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlZUG.jpg

(For all who ask why I do not read the information in the TestConsole like this:

```cs
            var sc = Properties.Settings.Default.PathToPython;
```

That is because I reuse the projects. In this case I have a TestConsole and I will add  service application. The TestConsole app is just for developing. But I don´t want to copy my code from one to another app. The TestConsol or later the service app gets as minimal code as possible.

a part of the app.config looks like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
<ToolkitConnector.Ui.TestConsole.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="PythonApp" serializeAs="String">
    <value>status.py</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="PathToPython" serializeAs="String">
    <value>python</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="OutputFolder" serializeAs="String">
    <value>c:\toolkit_1\status\statusOfPlatform1\</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="PySkriptWorkingDirectory" serializeAs="String">
    <value>c:\toolkit_1\</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LgInInformation" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value>
      <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <string>User1</string>
        <string>Pwd1</string>
        <string>GER_PROD</string>
        <string>18701</string>
        <string>Technology1</string>
        <string>User2</string>
        <string>Pwd2</string>
        <string>GER_PROD</string>
        <string>18795</string>
        <string>Technology2</string>
      </ArrayOfString>
    </value>
  </setting>
</ToolkitConnector.Ui.TestConsole.Properties.Settings>
```

In my project Logic.ControlAppSetting I use that code to read the xml file

```cs
        public void GetApplicationSetting(string path)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                doc.Load(path);
                XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                var applicationSettings = root.SelectSingleNode("applicationSettings");
                var mySettings = applicationSettings.SelectSingleNode("ToolkitConnector.Ui.TestConsole.Properties.Settings");
                foreach (XmlNode node in mySettings)
                {
                    var test = node.Attributes;
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Now I am looking for a elegant solution to store the settings information in variables. My problem is that I have different types like StringCollection and String. May be there is a better way to store this information?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

What I also tried:

```cs
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
            ConfigurationSectionGroup userSettings = config.GetSectionGroup("applicationSettings");
            ClientSettingsSection settings = (ClientSettingsSection)userSettings.Sections.Get("Ui.TestConsole.Properties.Settings");
            SettingElement elem = settings.Settings.Get("LgInInformation");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is not to make other libraries depend directly on this file or the auto-generated `Settings` class that's used to read its values. Your library doesn't need the file or the class. It just needs the values.

If your library depends on reading this file then it can only work in an environment where that file is present. That will make it difficult to use. Typically we can just add a reference to a library and use it. But if the library depends on this file then we would have to modify the application that uses the library to include these settings.

It's also going to make it difficult or impossible to write unit tests for your library. You'd have to add all of those settings to your unit test project too. But what if you want to write tests for the library using two different settings? That would be painful.

Instead, define an environment-agnostic class that contains exactly the settings this library needs.

In its simplest form,

```
public class MyLibraryConfigurationSettings
{
    public string PythonApp { get; set; }
    public List<string> LgInInformation { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then write your library so that in order to use it, the calling app must provide those settings.

Now you're done on the library side of it. In order to use it, you have to give it what it needs. It doesn't know or care where those values come from. It doesn't know if there's a configuration file or where it is.

Now your application must provide it to the library. It can do so by creating an instance of that class and populating it using `Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting`. Or it can populate it some other way. Now your application isn't forced to use that file either.

---

Another benefit of this approach is that it makes the requirement more explicit. For example, you can create your library so that adding it to your application requires providing the configuration values. For example, many libraries provide extensions for registering themselves with an `IServiceCollection`. You could do this:

```
services.AddYourLibrary(MyLibraryConfigurationSettings settings);
```

It's immediately clear that this is what the application must provide. You can make it easier by providing a class that can be easily deserialized.

If you depend on the file that relationship is less clear. You could add a reference to the library, write some code, and everything looks good. Then at runtime it throws an exception saying "Where's the file?" and the developer says, "What file?" and they have to look for documentation describing exactly how that file must be defined. It will be even more complicated if the file must be created using the `<applicationSettings>` section.

Comment: Thanks for your explatnation. But I think the idea of my project is not clear. The app.config is located in my _common folder in my Solution. From there I link that file to the Console and Service project. Now I don´t want to read the settings by each application (depends which I will compile). I want that function in an dll to use it for multiple projects. For debugging I will compile the Console App later on the Service App. Yes you are right that this dll will depend on that file but not on any other project. [link](https://imgur.com/a/c4Yz0xj)

Comment: Other projects will depend on that file if they depend on a dll that depends on the file. Ultimately everything depends on something, but a hard dependency on a file violates dependecy inversion. You could have an abstraction and one implementation reads from a file. But in that case why not use a JSON file instead of forcing yourself to use something which is apparently much more difficult to read? Just define a class, serialize/deserialize it using JSON, and the problem disappears.

Comment: In my app.config the information about my connection string is also stored. This information I can get by the dll. Just the other settings I will not get. I don´t want to have a json for one part of my settings and another part (connection string) is located in my app.config (which is always there). You think thats wrong? How would you design it? You have a service application (no GUI) you need to set up some settings including connection string. What is the best solution?

Comment: I don't like to ever say "wrong" because... I don't know why. It seems like the wrong thing to say. But I'd do it just the way I described it in my answer. If one of the values is a connection string then that would also be a part of that configuration settings class. We generally store settings with the application, even if they are used by other libraries. We can make it easier for the application to supply those values by providing a class that's easy to create or deserialize, but it can still tell the application what values it needs.

Comment: I think that I did. I try to deserialize the app.config which is stored in the application folder. The deserializing part I wanna do with a dll because I will use that function with different projects (see last screenshot). The app.config is store in the compiled project. If I call my deserializing call like this: `var test = new Logic.ControlAppSetting.ReadSettings();
            test.GetApplicationSetting(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);`

Comment: I'm sure that with effort you can get what you're attempting to work. But I've gone down that exact road. One of the reasons why it's difficult and weird is that the XML created in `<applicationSettings>` is created in a very customized way to be read by framework classes. Those classes allow you to read it and update it, which is a scenario that you likely don't need. That makes it much more painful to work with. Perhaps that's one reason why .NET is moving away from this altogether.